# Line regulator's oscillation , phase margin?

Tags: ldo, oscillation

Hi I'm studying LDO with LTspice, with tsmc180nm library.

During simulation, I cannot understand this situation...

[image]

[image]

I can obtain this OPEN LOOP GAIN simulation, with phase margin of 50 degrees, at 10mA current out.

So I run this with time transient simultion with current source that pull down 1mA~10mA . But I got this result.

[image]

For a step current, oscillation occurs.

I was wondering why this happens.

If I take C1 capacitor, miller cap's value of 100p, phase margin is 80 degrees and No oscillation occurs.

[image]

[image]

But I think that for 10pF capacitor circuit, oscillation must not occur too because I have 50 degrees of margin. Why this happens?

EDIT : I found that at Bodeplot, 0dB crossing frequency occurs once again after unity gain freq.

Can this be a problem?

Comment: Why should it oscillate - you don't appear to have any feedback?

Comment: I forgot to upload feedback circuit.. I erased that ac input signal and reconnected nmos input node to the node between two 3M resistors, then run the transient simulation..